# How do you deserialize a C# object in database using Python?

Tags: c#, python, serialization

We have an application that takes user data in C#, serializes it and puts it in a database.

I need to write an admin program in Python that takes that value and deserialize it.  I've tried using Pickle but I believe the format is different, because I keep getting errors.

Is this doable?

Thanks!

Edit 1: The type is binary -- here is the c# code that constructs it (where o is the object):

```
        using  ( MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream( ))
        {
            IFormatter myformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            myformatter.Serialize(stream, o);
            return stream.ToArray();}
```

Comment: How are you serializing it?  Xml, json, bson, binary?

Comment: .NET binary serialization uses a proprietary format, so it's probably not easy to decode...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/) so you can just use the .NET framework, like you did to save the data.